# Getting error while sending mail from postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, smtp

I am trying to send a simple mail from postgresql using plpythonu extension.Could someone please help me here to resolve the issue.

```py
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "PUBLIC".send_email()
     RETURNS integer
     LANGUAGE plpythonu
    AS $function$

    import smtplib 
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mailhost.XXX.com',587) 
    server.sendmail("Xyz@mail.com", "abc@mail.com", "hi")
    return 0
    $function$
```

while executing i am getting below error.

```
 SQL Error [38000]: ERROR: smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
  Where: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "send_email", line 5, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mailhost.XXX.com',587)
  PL/Python function "send_email", line 255, in __init__
  PL/Python function "send_email", line 316, in connect
  PL/Python function "send_email", line 364, in getreply
  PL/Python function "send_email"
```

Comment: Why you dont send the email from directly Python?

Comment: from your server database make a telnet mailhost.XXX.com 587    and check if you have connection or refused